# Reordering legend while modifying one particular line for a line chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a simple data frame as shown below:

```
> A <- data.frame(x=1:10, a=rep(1,10), d=rep(2,10), b=rep(3,10))
> A
    x a d b
1   1 1 2 3
2   2 1 2 3
3   3 1 2 3
4   4 1 2 3
5   5 1 2 3
6   6 1 2 3
7   7 1 2 3
8   8 1 2 3
9   9 1 2 3
10 10 1 2 3
```

I want to plot this with `x` on the x-axis and the other columns as lines on the y-axis. I want the line representing final column to be a little thicker than the other lines. So I can do this with the following code, which leads to the plot shown below it:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot that creates a thicker line for last column of data.
#However, order of legend is changed to alphabetical order.
p <- ggplot(A, aes(x))
for(i in 2:length(A)){
  gg.data <- data.frame(x=A$x, value=A[,i], name=names(A)[i])
  if(i==length(A)){
    p <- p + geom_line(data=gg.data, aes(y=value, color=name), size=1.1)
  } else{
    p <- p + geom_line(data=gg.data, aes(y=value, color=name))
  }
}
```

[image]

Now the problem with the plot above is that the order of the variables in the legend has changed to align with alphabetical order. I don't want that; instead I want the order to remain `a`,`d`,`b`.

I can keep the order as I wish by using `melt` and then plotting using the code below, but now I don't see how to increase the size of the line representing the last column in `A`.

```
Amelt <- melt(A, id.vars='x')
#Plot that orders legend according to order of columns in data frame.
#However, not sure how to thicken one particular line over the others.
pmelt <- ggplot(Amelt)+geom_line(aes(x=x, y=value, color=variable))
```

[image]

How can I get both things that I want?

Comment: You could potentially add the line for group of interest in a second, separate call to `geom_line`: `+ geom_line(data = subset(Amelt, variable == "b"), aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable), size = 1.1)`

Comment: Thanks, aosmith. That should work!

Comment: Just to make it relevant to the last variable instead of being hard-coded to "b": `+ geom_line(data = subset(Amelt, variable == Amelt$variable[nrow(Amelt)]), aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable), size = 1.1)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  using **scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("a","d","b"))** to specify the legends for the plots.

Please have a look at this link:
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, sachinv. But adding scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("a","d","b")) doesn't work. The legend is still in alphabetical order.